# How to flush pipe handle obtained from open?

Tags: perl

I am trying to flush a pipe handle obtained from [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) using either `autoflush()` and `flush()` methods from the [`IO::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle) module, but I think it is not working. Here is an example:

**host.pl**:

```perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $client_pid = open ( my $fh, '|-', 'client.pl' ) 
    or die "Could not open client: $!";
#$fh->autoflush(1);  # adding this line does not help
sleep 2;
say "Host: sent message";
print $fh "Hello";
#print $fh "Hello\n";  # adding a newline works fine
$fh->flush() or warn "$!";  # this does not work
sleep 2;
say "Host exits.";
close $fh;
```

**client.pl**:

```perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

say "Client running..";
chomp (my $line = <STDIN>);
say "Client got line: '$line'";
sleep 1;
say "Client exits..";
```

The output of running `host.pl` is:

```
Client running..
Host: sent message
Host exits.
Client got line: 'Hello'
Client exits..
```

Expected output would be:

```
Client running..
Host: sent message
Client got line: 'Hello'
Client exits..
Host exits.
```

I know I can fix this by adding a newline at the end of string to be printed:

```perl
print $fh "Hello\n";
```

but I am curious why `$fh->flush()` is not working here?

Comment: Because the client is using `readline`, so it's looping in `<STDIN>` until a `\n` arrives.

Comment: @melpomene Of course, I was blind! But then the question is if it is possible to read the message in an other way?

Comment: @Borodin I am curious why you edited the syntax highlighting using `language: lang-perl`? The syntax highlighting seemed fine to me also without adding the tag. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I added a syntax tag `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` at the top of your question, which disables all automatic syntax highlighting. Then I had to reenable Perl highlighting on the Perl sections. The problem was that the Perl highlighting on the output samples looked dreadful. To be honest it's not the greatest highlighter even on Perl code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is being sent to the client immediately, but the client waits for a newline to arrive.

---

`readline` (for which `<>` is a shortcut in your program) reads until a newline is encountered before returning (although changing `$/` can change that behaviour. If you want a call that returns as soon as data is available, use `sysread`.

```
use BLOCK_SIZE => 64*1024;

say "Client running..";
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread(\*STDIN, my $buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
   die($!) if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;
   say "Got: $buf";
}
```

Note a single print can result in data being received in multiple chunks. In practice, especially with a socket instead of a pipe, you'd need some way of framing your messages in order to reliably identify them. For example, the following client expects sentinel-terminated messages (the sentinel being a newline):

```
use BLOCK_SIZE => 64*1024;

say "Client running..";
my $buf = '';
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread(\*STDIN, $buf, BLOCK_SIZE, length($buf));
   die($!) if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;
   while ($buf =~ s/^([^\n]*)\n//) {
      my $msg = $1;
      say "Got: $msg";
   }

   say "Got a partial message" if length($buf);
}

die("Premature EOF\n") if length($buf);
```

Try sending:

```
$fh->autoflush();
print($fh "abc");
sleep(1);
print($fh "def\n");
sleep(1);
print($fh "ghi\njkl\nmno");
sleep(1);
print($fh "pqr\n");
```

This can be adapted to handle length-prefixed messages or any other message format.